# TFS "Go Online" changed files and outcome

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

I recently found [a SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496098/why-are-all-files-write-protected-and-how-can-i-check-in) / answer regarding not being able to edit a file that is TFS write protected. The answer involved right clicking the Solution and selecting "Go Online". After doing this, I have a plethora of adds/deletes that appear. These are mostly related to Nuget packages that I am not sure if / when I modified them. If I keep all these files selected, will it check in these changes automatically or put these files in my pending changes? More importantly, what exactly does "Go Online" modify/change and why should I have to set this, as my solution is already part of a TFS workspace?

Comment: could you post a link to the SO question and answer you referred to.

Comment: Sorry. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496098/why-are-all-files-write-protected-and-how-can-i-check-in

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you meed to know about how VS works with TFS on `offline/online` modes. See [When and how does my solution go "offline"?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benryan/2007/12/12/when-and-how-does-my-solution-go-offline/)

> If Visual Studio was open when TFS went off-line then it won’t allow
>   you to check out any files. If all your files are checked in already,
>   then you can just shut down Visual Studio and then start again. When
>   the solution opens it detects that TFS is gone and offers to open the
>   project in Offline mode.
>
> When TFS is available again you can simply reconnect to the server by
>   selecting the `Team -> Connect to Team Foundation Server…` menu. Once
>   you are connected, you can right-click the solution and select “`Go
>   Online`“.
>
> You’ll get a dialog that asks to to confirm the files that you’ve
>   changed in the meantime.
>
> **It will then take a few moments for TFS to catch up then the files appeared in the Pending Changes window ready to be checked in as
>   normal.**
>
> ***Source here:*** [Tip of the day: Getting Visual Studio with TFS to work
>   offline](https://colinmackay.scot/2011/08/31/tip-of-the-day-getting-visual-studio-with-tfs-to-work-offline/) for details.

Back to your questions:

- > **Q1** : will it check in these changes automatically or put these files in my
  >   pending changes?

  The changes will be catched up and appeared in the `Pending Changes`
  window ready to be checked in as normal.
- > **Q2** :  More importantly, what exactly does "Go Online" modify/change and why
  >   should I have to set this, as my solution is already part of a TFS
  >   workspace?

  Refer to above descriptions.

Another article for your reference:

[unbound TFS project - how do I get the offline changes checked in?](https://staxmanade.com/2008/10/unbound-tfs-project-how-do-i-get/)