# How to check out file in Visual studio code with TFVC?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc

I have TFS 2017 server which I integrated with my Visual studio code using visual studio team services plugin. I am able to login however when I edit any file and try to save, vs gives me error prompt.

Failed to save 'app.component.html': File is write protected. Select 'Overwrite' to attempt to remove protection.

How do I configure my VS code so that I can check out automatically like vs 2017 ?

[image]

Comment: Are you running VSCode as an admin?
This https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mde.checkout-tfs is used to check out file with team foundation server for VS Code.

Comment: @Mohammad This is a good answer. Remove the comment and post it as an answer.

Comment: This plugin is not working with VS2019 Enterprise and running VSCode in admin mode

Answer (score 0):

Please try below things to narrow down the issue:

- Try running the VS code as administrator to check if that works.
- You have lost the connection to the Team Foundation Server:

  In this case you can try to sign out then sign in again to reconnect.
  Alternately you can try removing the current workspace then create a
  new one and reconnect to TFS again using the new workspace. Reference
  this thread:
  [Why are all files write protected and how can I check-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496098/why-are-all-files-write-protected-and-how-can-i-check-in)
- The problem may be caused by some extensions installed for the VS
  code.

  In this case you can try resetting User/Project settings to their
  defaults and disabling vscode extensions to see if this is an issue
  with vscode or a specific extension. If doing this fixes the issue,
  try turning on the extensions one at a time and configuring the
  User/Project settings to what they were until the culprit is
  revealed. Reference [**nwayve's** comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13592#issuecomment-339993414) in this thread:https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13592
- Remove the visual studio team services plugin, then install it again
  and reconfigure it, you can reference [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056972/how-to-connect-tfs-in-visual-studio-code/48070466#48070466) in another
  thread to do that.

Comment: Same problem. Non of these helped. `Azure Repos` is the only installed extensions. On `Save` it shows same dialog. In case of `Overwrite` file saved but not checked out. On each file save executed: `tf status -noprompt -collection:path ******** -format:detailed -recursive dir` and `tf resolve -noprompt ******** dir -recursive -preview` (`dir` - local dir and `path` - tfs collection path, both are valid). However, nothing changes.

Comment: And if I manually checkout file (e.g., `tf checkout path`) everything else works well. Only automatic checkout on save not working.

Comment: TF used from VS2017.